# Misunderstand a algorithm

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

I fail to understand a algorithm, basically the matrix multiplication portion.

[image]

I can explain the unknown terms. At line no: 4 j will be 1,2,3,....,15. When ever new object is observed a value corresponding to this object assigned in j. There are total 15 objects. So when object number 1 observed it is assigned to j. j will be 1. If object no. 1 assigned again and again it will never assigned in j. J will be updated when object no. 2 is observed and so on.

Problem is in line no: 13 the matrix multiplication $H_t^i*\mu_t$. $\mu_t$ is 48*1 vector, where as  $H_t^i$ is a matrix with dynamic dimension. The number of column of $H_t^i$ will be change whenever the **value of j** will be change. But the for $\mu_t$ column will be remain static and it is 1. So when I implement it in matlab it give me a dimension mismatch error.

I think misunderstand this algorithm. Help me.

Comment: I don't understand our question. It seems that you don't understand the algorithm and you say you get a dimension mismatch error. So isn't the answer to "Can I misunderstand this algorithm and get a dimension mismatch error?" just "yes"? What's your actual question?

Comment: I get dimension mismatch error . So I want to know that why I get this error?